# Entendendo position, display e float em layout responsivo

Tags: javascript, html, css

Criei um "projeto" simples com `CSS`, `HTML` e `JS`, tendo a finalidade meu aprendizado. Contudo surgiram algumas dúvidas ao término do projeto (irei deixar o link do mesmo para download), [DropBox - Projeto](https://db.tt/l4TlkmMM).

Minha maior dúvida é em relação ao posicionamento de elementos na tela, li em diversos sites sobre `position`, `float` e `display`, mesmo assim não entendo a finalidade dos mesmos. Gostaria de ajuda para verificar se realizei o projeto de maneira prática ou inverti a ordem de `float` e `position`.

Confesso que não vi o porque usar `float` já que com `position` consigo flutuar em qualquer direção definindo `top` e `left`.

Obrigado.

Comment: Utilizar float e display pra montar layouts, ainda mais responsivos, cara você vai sofrer muito pra fazer. Pesquiso sobre grids ou frameworks html. É uma boa maneira de começar a trabalhar com responsividade

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

### Position

Defini o elemento com uma posição fixa, absoluta ou relativa, seja com base na página ou com base no seu elemento pai.

*Exemplo:*

```
/**
 * Neste caso, não importa se a div `elemento` é um elemento parent, child, se é o primeiro, último, etc.. 
 * este elemente sempre estará posisicionado a 10px do topo e 20px da lateral. SEMPRE.
 */
.elemento-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
}

/**
 * Neste caso, o elemento vai estar posicionado a 20px do topo em relação ao seu elemento pai.
 * Ou seja, se o elemento pai estiver a 100px de distância do topo, este elemento estará a 120px de distância.
 * Se o pai estiver a 260px, o elemento estará a 280px e assim por diante.
 */
.elemento-relative {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}

/**
 * Neste caso, o elemento terá uma posição absoluta de 20px do topo da página
 * Ou absolutamente a 20px do topo do seu elemento pai
 */
.elemento-absoluto {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}
```

Apenas com essa análise você pode se perguntar: **Mas então `relative` e `absolute` podem ter o mesmo resultado?** R.: Sim e não.

Isso vai depender da interação e combinação entre eles.

- *Se não houver elemento pai*: A posição é relativa ao body
- *Se houver elemento pai, mas sem position definido*: A posição é relativa ao body
- *Se houver elemento pai com position*: relative: A posição do elemento filho é relativa ao elemento pai

---

### Float

O `float` já possui um propósito muito diferente do `position`. Ele vai "flutuar" o seu elemento em relação ao elemento pai.

*Exemplo:*

```
.el-float {
    float: left;
}
```

Ou seja, left vai alinhar seu elemento à esquerda, right à direita, none sem alinhamento, etc..

E aí, de novo, você deve se perguntar: Mas com um position absolute eu posso obter o mesmo resultado. R.: Sim. MAS! Você está falando de layout responsivo, de layout que pode interagir com outros elementos, onde nem sempre usar position é a solução. Afinal de contas, pra que tantas propriedades se tudo fosse resolvido assim?

Veja um exemplo bem prático. Uma lista de menu com alinhamento a direita:

```css
ul {
  width: 180px;
  border: 1px solid #212121;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  background:white;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.first li {
  width: 80px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: right;
}

ul.second {
  position: relative;
}
ul.second li {
  width: 80px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="first">
    <li>Menu 01</li>
    <li>Menu 02</li>
    <li>Menu 03</li>
    <li>Menu 04</li>
</ul>

<ul class="second">
    <li>Menu 01</li>
    <li>Menu 02</li>
    <li>Menu 03</li>
    <li>Menu 04</li>
</ul>
```

Viu a grande diferença entre o `float` e o `position`?

Na primeira opção ele se alinha corretamente, na segunda todos os elementos ficam "amontoados". Você poderia contornar a situação mas precisaria definir uma posição "top" para cada elemento li, fazer o cálculo e.. bom, você já deve imaginar o trabalho que isso daria.

---

### Display

O Display já não se enquadra nesse quesito. Quer dizer, ele interfere um poco no comportamento dos elementos, mas não tanto quanto essa sua dúvida.